# Image gets duplicated in imageloader

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using `imageloader` in `getView()` like below. But I am not able to get the `ic_launcher` as a default image when `picturepath` is empty. I don't know what's going wrong. But when I debug, I am able to find that it goes to else part itself when picturepath is empty. But still somehow the existed imagepaths image gets loaded. That too this happens only for the first row of the list. Can some one please help me solve the issue?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder vh = null;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = View.inflate(context, layoutResourceId, null);
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                vh.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

                vh.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

                convertView.setTag(vh);
            }else{
                vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            String picturePath = detailsUrl.get(position);

            vh.nameTextView.setText("Name: "+name);
            if(picturePath !=null && !picturePath.equals(""))
            {
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+picturePath , vh.imageView);
            }
            else
            {
                     // I am able to see here the control flows when the imagepath is empty
                vh.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);  
            }


        return (row);       
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try .resetViewBeforeLoading() with DisplayImageOptions.

```
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to setup if else statements.
Set your "DisplayImageOptions" as follow

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) //and other options you may need
            .build();
```

then after this statement

> vh.nameTextView.setText("Name: "+name);

put this block of code

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(image_poster_url, vh.imageView, options);
```

if the url is null or empty url, this will automatically display the ic_launcher.
if still image gets duplicated add this block to the DisplayImageOptions before .build();

```
.resetViewBeforeLoading()
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks for your reply. I have already tried this. This resolves the duplication issue, but it shows IO Exception in the logcat. Of course it doesn't give force close. But still I want to avoid this error. Can you please suggest?